# BAD URL Error because I changed from 24hour to am/pm

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

```
2014-07-20 09:29:22.561 EE[4636:60b] Ticket/3B0281/33/2014-07-20T10:00 am:00
2014-07-20 09:29:22.625 EE[4636:60b] Request Failed with Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x15ed01a0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x15e99620 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}
```

FROM THIS:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
        NSDate *alertTime = [formatter dateFromString:str];
        //NSDate *alertTime = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:60];
```

TO

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy h:mm:ss a"];
        NSDate *alertTime = [formatter dateFromString:str];
        //NSDate *alertTime = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:60];
```

I got the above error message after changing from 24hr to am/pm, please what did I do wrong in this case?

Based on @skrew suggestion here is what I used in my code:

```
    static NSString AFPercentEscapedQueryStringPairMemberFromStringWithEncoding(NSString   *string, NSStringEncoding encoding) {
// Escape characters that are legal in URIs, but have unintentional semantic significance when used in a query string parameter
static NSString * const kAFLegalCharactersToBeEscaped = @":/.?&=;+!@$()~";

return [(NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,   (CFStringRef)string, NULL, (CFStringRef)kAFLegalCharactersToBeEscaped, CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding)) autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Changing what from 24hr to am/pm?

Comment: Show us how you build the URL — most likely your `NSDateFormatter` code. If "en_US_POSIX" means nothing to you then there's a pat answer waiting for you at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html

Comment: This error occur when you are not creating valid url. Like you are not appending http://someurl.com

Answer (score 1):

You have to encode the URL because you have now a space (10:00 am)

Add NSString+URLEncoding.h:

```
- (NSString *)urlEncode;
```

Add NSString+URLEncoding.m:

```
- (NSString *)urlEncode
{
    return (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                                            (__bridge CFStringRef)self,
                                                                            NULL,
                                                                            (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[] ",
                                                                            kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
}
```

In your code, when you build your url, add:

```
NSString *url = [url urlEncode];
```

If you dont want all code above, a quickfix (**but not recommended**) if to replace your space in url

```
url = [url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @"%20"];
```